# Displaying an image in a specific area of an image map

Tags: html, image, dictionary

I'm creating an image map from my office floor plan.

I've used GIMP to specify all the relevant areas (i.e. occupied cubes).
I have the resulting HTML.

Now I want to show a dropdown menu of names next to the map.
When someone chooses a name from the menu, I want to display an arrow pointing at the correct cube where that person sits.

I think that means I need a table of some sort that maps Employee Names to the image map coordinates of their cube. Also, since names change more often than cube numbers, I was thinking of doing 2 tables:

Table 1 = Image Map Coords to Cube #s.
Table 2 = Cube #s to People Names.
Or maybe it's just 1 table, I'm really lost here.

When someone chooses a name from the menu, I need some code that looks up the name/item ID and finds the matching Image Map Coords, then displays the arrow image at that location.

I would be willing to settle for highlighting the specified area. In fact, that might even be easier, but I don't know.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
David

Comment: Is your goal to do this in a single, self-contained HTML file, or do you want a database on the server and dynamically generate the HTML file?

Comment: Hmmm...haven't thought that far ahead I guess. I'm using Google sites. They have a page template called "List" which appears to be a rudimentary internal database of sorts. I was thinking I'd use that as the interface for people to add/edit their info including their names and Cube IDs. I haven't thought it through any more than that.  P.S. I can edit the HTML for any of the pages and have already successfully put up a working image map.

Comment: There is a plugin for this: http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/demo_simple.html

Comment: Thanks, Diodeus. Is JQuery a plugin for Google Sites or for GIMP?

Comment: @user2792804, neither.  JQuery is a javascrpt plugin you can use on any HTML page.

Comment: Sweet. Thanks for that. I'll tinker with it and see if I can get it to do what I need. Thanks for the help!